# How does a 3.6915 petawatt laser with a temperature of 368,000,000 Degrees Celsius compare to current day lasers?

Tags: laser, power

Imagine that humans eventually develop a [Directed-Energy Weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed-energy_weapon) which produces a laser with a destructive power output of 3.6915 petawatts and an average temperature of 368 million degrees celsius at the center of the laser.

How would the power of the laser compare to the power used by common household appliances and modern lasers?

Comment: The answer is in the title. The power would be $3.6915$ petawatts. You have to start being careful with a laser at around $5$ milliwatts.

Comment: What is the significance of 3.6915 petawatts versus, say, 3.6914 petawatts? Why are you being so precise?

Comment: @mmesser314 Yeah, thanks for pointing that out. I’m really asking how it compares to current day lasers, so I’m changing the title rn.

Comment: @Ghoster I’m being this precise for a complicated reason. I can’t really fit the explanation in as many characters as are allowed by the site.

Comment: Why do you think a laser beam has a [temperature](https://www.eurolaser.com/customer-service/faq/how-hot-is-actually-the-laser-beam/)?

Comment: @Ghoster I’m not an expert in anything to do with physics. I’m a writer. I’m legit only here because 1) I use a lot of science in my stories and  2) I found out worldbuilding.stackexchange doesn’t take fanfic-related questions. No joke.

Comment: _worldbuilding.stackexchange doesn’t take fanfic-related questions_ But almost all questions posted there are based on imaginary worlds and realities. I'd have thought questions along the lines of this one would be welcome there.

Answer (score 2):

Laser beams do not have temperatures. [Petawatt lasers](https://www6.slac.stanford.edu/news/2021-10-07-department-energy-gives-green-light-flagship-petawatt-laser-facility-slac) are rare, but they do exist. You can get a sense for what levels of power output are required for which applications. For reference, a petawatt is 1,000,000,000,000,000 watts. It's also important to point out that high power lasers don't operate in continuous wave mode; they pack a not-wholly-unreasonable amount of energy into an extremely short pulse. A continuous wave petawatt laser would require [500 times the global electrical power demand](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+petawatt+%2F+electricity+consumption+of+the+world).

[image]

Comment: Every realisable system has some form of thermodynamics in it. The laser would have some equivalent temperature; even the population inversion would have a negative temperature coupled to an effective temperature. For example, the laser cannot be used to make a thing hotter than its effective temperature. But of course, it is not a simple thermal distribution and everything.

Comment: Most likely to OP means how how the target hit by the laser gets.